# Generating JWT RS256 signature with openssl

Tags: rsa, signature, openssl

I'm trying to sign a JWT token with the RS256 algorithm using `openssl`. Take the following example token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ
```

Per [RFC 7518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518), RS256 means the signature used is "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 using SHA-256". My understanding is that the following use of `openssl dgst` would do:

```
# generate the key
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048

# generate the signature
echo 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ' | \
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.pem -binary | \
openssl base64 | \
tr -- '+/=' '-_ '
```

However, trying to use jwt.io to verify results in invalid signature. Furthermore, using jwt.io to generate a signature using the same private key produces a completely different one.

What am I doing wrong? Is `openssl dgst` the correct way to sign this token?

Comment: Since this is about how to use a piece of software, it appears to be more on-topic for a site like superuser rather than crypto.stackexchange. I can migrate this there for you.

Comment: `echo` echoes its argument(s) _as a line_ -- meaning it **adds a newline** character. On _some_ systems or shells `-n` suppresses this, but [`printf '%s' 'string'` is _reliably_ correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: Right, it was indeed the newline. Thanks! Mind adding a reply so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` echoes its argument(s) as a line -- meaning it adds a newline character. On some systems or shells `-n` suppresses this, but [`printf '%s' 'string'` is reliably correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

```
# generate the key
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048

# generate the signature
printf '%s' 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ' | \
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.pem -binary | \
openssl base64 | \
tr -- '+/=' '-_ '
```